# Netbeans IDE 6.9.1 not opening

Tags: ruby, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-6.9

I am using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 with jdk8u45 on my Windows 7 enterprise 64 bit machine for Java,php,JSP development.Recently i heard from my friend that Netbeans IDE also supports Ruby development.Later I found that Netbeans IDE ended the support for Ruby Development on version 7.So,I downloaded Netbeans 6.9.1 with Ruby Package from Netbeans website and Installed on my machine.The package contains Glassfish Sever community edition too and installed successfully.But, Netbeans 6.9.1 is not opening.

**Is there anyone succeeded using Netbeans for Ruby development in Win7 64 bit machine?**...Please help me or ***suggest me a better IDE for Ruby development***,I am already experienced with Netbeans,Visual Studio and Eclipse..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem.
The problem is with the jdk.

**Netbeans IDE 6.9.1 and 8.0.2 works very well with jdk 7u72.
And Netbeans IDE 6.9.1 can't start with jdk 8u45,because a runtime exception is occurs.**

<strike>Now,I am in a confusion.
jdk 8 is not a replacement for jdk 7.Sun microsystems giving support for both jdk 7 & 8.
I am using jdk for android development(as dependency for both android studio and eclipse with ADT plug-in),java development(as dependency for Netbeans IDE 8.02),
as dependency for php development using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2,as dependency for ruby development using Netbeans IDE 6.9.1.
Which jdk is suitable in my case-jdk 7 or 8 or both (selecting appropriate jdk for appropriate application by passing cmd arguments)?
my development environment is win 7 enterprise 64 bit...</strike>

Update : The support for jdk7 is ended & according to oracle, users must migrate to jdk8. So, we must use jdk8 and avoid use of jdk7.

Update : Install ruby plugin from official Netbeans plugin repository via plugin manager. The ruby plugin for netbeans (early, it is embedded in netbeans installation as in the case of netbeans 6.9.1 and earlier versions. But later it is removed and available as a plugin as in the case of netbeans versions after 6.9.1) is a fully matured development package for Ruby including rails via jruby & supports all latest Netbeans versions.